# Xcode Unit Tests returns the NSURL of temp folder without 'private keyword'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing

I am writing Unit Tests in `Objective C`.

The following is my code:

```
NSString *testTempDirectory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"DC_Tests"];
NSURL *parentDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:testTempDirectory];
NSURL *testFolderURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:testFolderPath];
```

Now the path in testFolderURL is returned as

```
/var/folders/31/2dpztnmx4fzfxb87qtn5_n0wc49pvz/T/DC_Tests/testFolder/
```

But the original path is

```
/private/var/folders/31/2dpztnmx4fzfxb87qtn5_n0wc49pvz/T/DC_Tests/testFolder/
```

The original path is my expected path and since it is different, my assertion is failing.

Any idea as to how do I get the complete path.

**Note**: I tried absolute string, doesn't help.

Comment: `NSTemporaryDirectory()` always return current user temp directory path not 
 private folder path please check it agin 
your path looks like : 
 /Users/userName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/246CD9D7-5C58-4762-8A69-DA9378D626A3/data/Containers/Data/Application/C29BD648-6E6F-49D1-AE6E-F6567C8949B0/tmp/DC_Tests

Comment: Hi @CodeChanger, That's great help. But is there any way possible where i get the path with private in it. Since this is a unit test, I don't want to resort on manipulating the strings returned.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in Mac OS, the `var` folder is actually a linked folder to `/private/var`

```
$ ls -l /
total 45
drwxrwxr-x+ 61 root  admin  2074 Jun 11 08:58 Applications
drwxr-xr-x+ 63 root  wheel  2142 Jul  6  2016 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root  wheel    68 Aug 24  2015 Network
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   136 Jun  9 18:56 System
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin   204 Apr 22  2016 Users
drwxrwxrwt@  4 root  admin   136 Jun 15 09:53 Volumes
drwxr-xr-x@ 39 root  wheel  1326 Jun  9 18:56 bin
drwxrwxr-t@  2 root  admin    68 Aug 24  2015 cores
dr-xr-xr-x   3 root  wheel  4312 Jun  9 18:57 dev
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Oct 18  2015 etc -> private/etc
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Jun  9 18:58 home
-rw-r--r--@  1 root  wheel   313 Aug 23  2015 installer.failurerequests
dr-xr-xr-x   2 root  wheel     1 Jun  9 18:58 net
drwxr-xr-x@  6 root  wheel   204 Oct 18  2015 private
drwxr-xr-x@ 59 root  wheel  2006 Jun  9 18:56 sbin
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Oct 18  2015 tmp -> private/tmp
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 root  wheel   442 Apr 19  2016 usr
lrwxr-xr-x@  1 root  wheel    11 Oct 18  2015 var -> private/var
```

So the simplest way to fix your test is to ignore the `/private` part from the path. (We had a similar issue with paths that contain the `tmp` folder on Mac OS as well)

Comment: Hi @Dat Nguyen, how do you suggest we ignore it? Should we manipulate the string?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that in your test, you can have your expected path to the `/var/folder/...` instead of `/private/var/folder/...`. If this path is given by some other library or API, you can just trim the `/private` path. We did the same in our code.

Comment: Currently trimming the path. Just wanted to know if there is any API for the same

Comment: I'm not aware of any API that does the trimming automatically for you. This could well be just a Mac thing (linking `/var` with `/private/var`).